# if() action lost on pjax page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, pjax

My code is :

```
  if ( $( "*" ).hasClass( "cover" ) ) {
    $(".cover").backstretch( $(".cover").data('src'), {fade: 350} );
  }
```

It executes properly is it is a standard page laod, but not on pjax navigation.

Any idea how to get it work ?

EDIT :

```
  if ( $(".cover").length ) {
    $(".cover").backstretch( $(".cover").data("src"), {fade: 400} );
  };
  $(document).on('pjax:complete', function() {
    if ( $(".cover").length ) {
      $(".cover").backstretch( $(".cover").data("src"), {fade: 400} );
    }
  })
```

Comment: so when do you call this code? Any handler???

Comment: `if ( $(".cover").length )` should have much more performance than your current condition. On topic, look at the DevTools console for errors.

Comment: It's only in my main.js js file... How should I call it ?

Comment: That is one badly performing selector in the OP's post!

Comment: you should recall it in callback function of load() method

Comment: How can I do this ? (Sorry, I'm new to js... I'm learning it by coding...)

Comment: @FabrícioMatté In this context, he shouldn't need the if statement at all. If `$('.cover')` doesn't select anything, nothing will happen.

Comment: Off topic, if ( $(".cover").length ) seems way more clever than my solution... what exactly is the difference ?

Comment: provide relevant code where you are using ajax (.load()???)

Comment: $(document).pjax("a:not('.no-pjax')", '#pjax-container');
  NProgress.configure({ minimum: 0.66 });
  $(document).on('pjax:send', function() { NProgress.start(); })
  $(document).on('pjax:complete', function() { NProgress.done(); })
  $(document).on('pjax:timeout', function(event) {   event.preventDefault(); })

  if ( $( "*" ).hasClass( "cover" ) ) {
    $(".cover").backstretch( $(".cover").data('src'), {fade: 350} );
  }

Comment: @JasonP `backstretch` is not a built-in jQuery method, custom methods are not warranted to follow the convention (e.g. may have additional initialization and overhead besides the regular `.each()` iteration).

Comment: Use pjax:complete callback to recall your code if your posted code is relevant to your question which i'm not really sure

Comment: @ A. Wolff : So I must have two times my code for standard loads too right ?

Comment: @Ziplo The difference is that `$('*').hasClass()` will select every element in the page and test each one to check whether it has the given class. `$('.cover').length` will use the best method which the browser provides to find elements with the `cover` class (e.g. `document.getElementsByClassName`) and return the amount of elements with that class (0 is a falsy value, any other `.length` value is a truthy value).

Comment: I edited the OP tho get my current code. does i seem ok to you ? (It works, but is it the best solution ?)
Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: As noted in the comments you don't need to test for `$('.cover').length` as if `$('.cover')` does not match anything, the `backstretch` function won't be run.

Comment: But if there is no .cover, won't it return an error ?

Comment: `function displayCover() {
  if ( $(".cover").length ) {
    $(".cover").backstretch( $(".cover").data("src"), {fade: 400} );
  }
}

$(document).displayCover;

$(document).on('pjax:complete', function() {
 displayCover;
})`

It doesn't work any more (it's in main.js). What is the problem here ?

EDIT : stupid question, it's displayCover();